# How to remove object from array in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have array like this:

```
var myMovie = [];
```

And object like this:

```
var first = {id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"}
```

I **added** object into local storage array via `OnClick()` on button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn.btn-outline-success").click(function () {

    myMovie.push(first); 

    localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
    var output = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myMovie'));
```

After **adding** object into local storage, local storage looks like this:

```
[{id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"}]
```

My question here is, how could I **remove** whole object via variable name? I want to remove object `first` from `myMovie`. Index position of object may be **different** each time.

```
[{id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"}, [{id:"tt9574821", title:"Ghost Protocol", year:"2012", type:"Action, Adventure"}]
```

Comment: This is a different example, and I also tried your solution, but it doesn't apply to my code.

Comment: nope. The code stays the same.

Comment: Problem whit your previous code is that nothing happens, I just get some console errors. Could you show me example for this code?

Comment: you want to convert `first` to index?? You mean if the variable name is `second`, you want to remove item at second index??

Comment: I want to remove this object `{id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"`} from array `myMovie` even if is on second index or third in array.

Comment: If is possible I want to match object `first` in array `myMovie` and if exist, then delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be a function, that not only changes the array but also stores it in localStorage.

To find the right index to remove, you could find the object with the right title:

```js
    var myMovie=[] //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myMovie')||"[]");
    
    function push(el){
    myMovie.push(el);
    //localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
    }

    function remove(title){
     var i=myMovie.findIndex(movie=>movie.title===title);
     if(i!==-1){
       myMovie.splice(i,1);
       //localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
     }
    }
    
    push({id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"});
    console.log(myMovie);
    remove("La La Land");
    console.log(myMovie);
```

To make a running stackSnippet, i had to remove the localStorage functionality, it is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to have your object in format

```
var first = {"tt3783958": { title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"}}
```

ID will make your object have unique keys. Update will also be easy.

And store these in a JSON object and not an array like

```
myMovie = {}; //note its an object
```

This would make it easier for you to query and delete items.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the object and set new one:

```
myMovie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myMovie"));
myMovie.splice(0,1);
localStorage.setItem("myMovie",JSON.stringify(myMovie));
```

Comment: This seems to create new empty 'myMovie' array. And its set to delete first index instead of deleting via variable name 'first'.